# Python 3 - Login to site that requires Facebook login

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, python-3.2

I have previously built scripts to login to sites using tradition username and password fields. I was wondering how do I go about logging into a site with Python that requires Facebook authentication. Specifically, what information do I need from the site and can you provide a sample script. I am using Python 3.

Comment: You need something like [this](http://facebook-python-library.docs-library.appspot.com/facebook-python/examples/oauth.html)?